# OnClickListener NullPointerExpection Java

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I have build a RecyclerViewer application in Java using android studio.
When I run the app it crashes, when I checked the Logcat I found there is a null pointer exception in my Adapter.
`onBindViewHolder` method.
This covers line 49.

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ContactsAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.txtName.setText(contacts.get(position).getName());
        holder.txtName.setText(contacts.get(position).getEmail());
        Glide.with(context).asBitmap().load(contacts.get(position).getImage()).into(holder.image);

        holder.parent.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(context, contacts.get(position).getName() + " Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });


    }
```

Logcat log

```
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.cardview.widget.CardView.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.learningapplication.ContactsAdapter.onBindViewHolder(ContactsAdapter.java:49)
        at com.example.learningapplication.ContactsAdapter.onBindViewHolder(ContactsAdapter.java:19)
```

EDIT:
Here is the full code:

```
package com.example.learningapplication;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.cardview.widget.CardView;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ContactsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ContactsAdapter.ViewHolder>{
    private Context context;

    ArrayList<Contacts> contacts = new ArrayList<>();

    public void setContacts(ArrayList<Contacts> contacts) {
        this.contacts = contacts;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public ContactsAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public ContactsAdapter() {
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.contacts_layout, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ContactsAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.txtName.setText(contacts.get(position).getName());
        holder.txtName.setText(contacts.get(position).getEmail());
        Glide.with(context).asBitmap().load(contacts.get(position).getImage()).into(holder.image);

        holder.parent.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(context, contacts.get(position).getName() + " Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return contacts.size();
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        private TextView txtName;
        private TextView txtEmail;
        private ImageView image;
        private CardView parent;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            txtName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtName);
            txtEmail = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtEmail);
            image = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image);

        }

    }
}

``
```

Comment: 30 lines of differences between methods tells me we're not seeing the entire code, but the answer is likely the same: `holder.parent` is null.

Comment: What is parent this seems to be null add code snippet for parent view

Comment: I have added the whole code.

Comment: Please initialize your card view in your viewholder.

Comment: Thank you :)
All I need is to initialize the card view - `parent = itemView.findViewById(R.id.parent);`
`private CardView parent;`

Answer (score 0):

as i understand:
`holder.parent` - this is `null`
check your initializations

Comment: This is supposed to be a Comment.

Comment: (Keep in mind new users cannot leave comments until 50 reputation @PrajwalWaingankar )

Comment: when i posted this there was only onBindViewHolder code. And i cant ask for more information in Answer, so, how can i answer than?